# How to provide a convenient link to next post in Ghost Framework (Blog)

Tags: ghost-blog

Is there a way to conveniently provide a link to the next post in the Ghost Blogging Platform?

How to do that?

Ideally it would be dynamic.  Therefore if I change the title of the next post I would not have to go to the post and manually change it there since it will know the details of the next post has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `{{next_post}}` helper to do that. Inside this helper, you can use the usual [post attributes](https://themes.ghost.org/docs/post-context), like the `url` or `title`.
Here's the implementation from my blog theme:

```
 <div class="next-post">
   {{#next_post}}                                        
     <a href="{{url}}"> Next <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> </a>                    
     <a href="{{url}}" class="title"> {{title}} </a>
   {{/next_post}}
 </div>
```

Here's more in the documentation: https://themes.ghost.org/docs/prev_next_post

Comment: Hi Will this work in the editor?   or does this have to be in the template files?

Comment: This can be used in the template files of your theme.